# Как сделать приложение, которое одновременно консольное и оконное?

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу сделать приложение, которое в зависимости от параметров командной строки, будет консольным или оконным. Например, будучи запущенным из cmd.exe чтобы выводило информацию в консоль. А в другом случае показывало окно и никакой консоли.
Т.е. по сути как в Linux.

Comment: Пятый раз перехватываю консоль и снова забываю поставить `STARTUPINFO.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`

Answer (score 1):

Простого способа добиться требуемого функционала [нет][1]. Подсистема исполнения является частью PE и прошивается на этапе сборки. Можно придумать какие-нибудь обходные пути, по ссылке выше есть ссылка на какие-то «решения». Я, в свою очередь, предложил бы иметь для такого случае 3 исполняемых файла. Первый будет диспетчером, который будет запускать тот, или иной процесс, в зависимости от переданных аргументов. Это будет консольная утилита. Два других исполняемых файла будут консольной и GUI реализацией требуемого функционал, которые диспетчер и будет запускать.

---

Попробовал в роли диспетчера batch файл. Пусть консольной программой будет batch файл program.bat, следующего содержания:

```
@echo off
dir
```

GUI-программой будет калькулятор. Тогда диспетчер(test.bat) будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "1" (
    start /B program.bat
) else (
    start calc.exe
)
```

Запускаем из консоли `test.bat 1` — получаем вывод `dir` в той же консоли, запускаем `test.bat 2` — получаем новое окно калькулятора.
[1]: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/?p=19643

Comment: Если диспетчером будет консольная утилита, то при запуске будет показываться окно консоли.

Comment: Понятно, что приложение не может быть одновременно консольным и оконным, это ограничение Windows, но может как-то можно сэмулировать нужное поведение?

Comment: @zenden2k, окно покажется и сразу скроется. Т.е. диспетчер живёт всего секунду.

Comment: даже на секунду это некрасиво

Comment: Наверно можно в диспетчере вначале писать `FreeConsole` но это не сильно поможет, т.к. консоль создается раньше.

Comment: @zenden2k, а если попробовать в качестве диспетчера простой батник?

Comment: Для батника тоже создается окно консоли

Comment: @zenden2k, обновил ответ

Comment: @zenden2k, кстати, в качестве «диспетчера» можно использовать и GUI приложение, в котором не показывать никакого окна. Таким образом будет создана иллюзия, что ничего вообще н запускалось

Comment: Если в качестве диспетчера использовать GUI приложение, консольное приложение запустится в новой консоли, а редирект работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. 
Пытаемся подключиться к консоли родительского процесса, в случае неудачи создаем новую консоль с помощью `AllocConsole`. Редирект в файл `app.exe > file.txt` также работает. 
Подводные камни: cmd.exe **не ждет** завершения процесса и программа по сути не контролирует консоль. Интересно было бы узнать о других подводных камнях.

Нашел на английском SO [развернутый ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494000/4569791) о всех подводных камнях. Получается, для грамотного решения поставленной задачи промелькивающее окно консоли - это неизбежность.

```
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

bool IsRedirected(HANDLE handle)
{
    DWORD fileType = GetFileType(handle);

    return (fileType == FILE_TYPE_DISK) || (fileType == FILE_TYPE_PIPE);
}

HANDLE hStdOutDup, hStdErrDup, hStdOut, hStdErr;
void BindStdHandlesToConsole()
{
    if (IsRedirected(hStdOut)) {
        SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hStdOut);
    }

    if (IsRedirected(hStdErr) ){
        SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hStdErr);
    }

    //Redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
    HANDLE stdInHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (stdInHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)stdInHandle, _O_TEXT);
        if (fileDescriptor != -1) {
            FILE* file = _fdopen(fileDescriptor, "r");
            if (file != NULL) {
                *stdin = *file;
                setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    //Redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    HANDLE stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (stdOutHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)stdOutHandle, _O_TEXT);
        if (fileDescriptor != -1) {
            FILE* file = _fdopen(fileDescriptor, "w");
            if (file != NULL) {
                *stdout = *file;
                setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    //Redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    HANDLE stdErrHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    if (stdErrHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)stdErrHandle, _O_TEXT);
        if (fileDescriptor != -1) {
            FILE* file = _fdopen(fileDescriptor, "w");
            if (file != NULL) {
                *stderr = *file;
                setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    //Clear the error state for each of the C++ standard stream objects. We need to do this, as
    //attempts to access the standard streams before they refer to a valid target will cause the
    //iostream objects to enter an error state. In versions of Visual Studio after 2005, this seems
    //to always occur during startup regardless of whether anything has been read from or written to
    //the console or not.
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::cout.clear();
    std::wcerr.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::wcin.clear();
    std::cin.clear();
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    int argCount;
    LPWSTR* szArgList = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argCount);
    std::wstring mode;

    if (argCount > 1) {
        mode = szArgList[1];
    }

    if (mode == L"gui") {
        MessageBox(0, _T("Gui Mode"), _T("Console/Windows app"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else {
        //Get a pointer to the forground window.  The idea here is that
        //IF the user is starting our application from an existing console
        //shell, that shell will be the uppermost window.  We'll get it
        //and attach to it
        HWND wnd = GetForegroundWindow();

        DWORD processId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &processId);

        hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        hStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

        if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)) //Is the uppermost window a cmd process?
        {
            BindStdHandlesToConsole();
            //we have a console to attach to ..
            std::cout << "hello. It looks like you started me from an existing console.";
        }
        else {
            //no console AND we're in console mode ... create a new console.
            AllocConsole();
            BindStdHandlesToConsole();
            std::cout << "hello. It looks like you double clicked me to start AND you want console mode.Here's a new console.";
            fgetc(stdin);
        }

        FreeConsole();
    }

    LocalFree(szArgList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Еще один подводный камень - такая программа криво запускается из FAR manager: ФАР видит, что процесс оконный, поэтому сразу после запуска снова показывает свои панели. Тут-то запущенная программа подсоединяется к консоли обратно и начинает писать поверх панелей ФАРа...

Comment: @PavelMayorov cmd.exe делает то же самое. Интересно, есть ли способ это обойти.

Comment: Тогда надо вывернуть логику обратно: делать изначально консольное приложение - а при необходимости освобождать консоль с помощью `FreeConsole`. Недостаток - "промелькивающая" консоль при "оконном" запуске - зато драки за консоль с `cmd.exe` и `far.exe` не будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нашел на английском SO развернутый ответ о всех подводных камнях http://stackoverflow.com/a/494000/4569791
Получается, для грамотного решения поставленной задачи промелькивающее окно консоли - это неизбежность.

Comment: @zenden2k: Ну, проблема вроде бы возникает лишь если вы хотите писать в консоль, с которой программа запущена.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно вынести основную логику в DLL, а для запуска сделать два разных исполнимых файла; консольный и оконный. Так сделано, к примеру, в Java (`java.exe` и `javaw.exe`).