Взаимодействие с консолью в WinAPI
Сейчас я пишу интерпретатор своего языка на Си с использованием WinAPI (точка входа WinMain). Я хотел бы иметь несколько способов запуска скриптов на нем написанном:

Открытие файла с моим расширением (как .exe)
Открытие через консоль с указанием пути к файлу (как python path\to\file.py)

Так вот, в первом случае у меня нет консоли, а во втором - есть. Однако, в программе на моем языке могут быть аналоги функций print/cout/write и input/cin/read (не обязательно в каждом приложении, некоторые используют GUI, им консоль не нужна), работающие с консолью. так что, даже если ее нет, мне придется ее каким-то образом создавать, общаться с ней.
И, пока, я не очень хорошо понимаю, как мне отслеживать хотя бы наличие открытой консоли и тем более выводить в нее информацию, поскольку классические printf не работают.
В конечном итоге, я хотел бы, чтобы интерпретатор, в случае запуска с консоли, выводил данные в эту же консоль и читал из нее, а если консоли нет, то запускал новую и работал уже с ней.
Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо.

"...Сейчас я пишу интерпретатор своего языка на Си..." - а мне нравится начало, боевой задор, планы внутри планов... Дело за малым... Есть такой себе язык, не поверите, тоже С, только с приставкой #. Работа с консолью в нём реализована нативно и без изобретения велосипедов. Пока Вы напишете, консоль исчезнет в Windows. За ненадобностью. Мой Вам совет: назовите вещи своими именами и тогда будет понятно что делать. Все профи не "языки" какие-то нелепые пишут, а библиотеки часто используемых ними функций.

Пробуйте что-то такое: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443067/240512

@SmallSoft Спасибо, почитал и выбрал для себя подходящий вариант, наверно, остановлюсь на костыле Джавы. Еще раз спасибо!

@FoxFox просто, мне стало интересно как работают ЯП, хотя бы интерпретируемые. ну и хочется, чтобы было красиво, без ненужных консолей

Если есть куча ненужного времени и гигаватты ненужной энергии, кто ж против? Языки сегодня не создаются одиночками, да ещё и неопытными. И даже это ещё не всё. Многие почему-то думают, что вот они операционную систему напишут, мессенджер, Ютюб и все так и побежали туда. Не побежали, не бегут и не будут бежать. А потом эти писатели ютюбов сидят и думают, куды я десять лет жизни угробил?
